# SwiftUI: How to add a value near the disclosure indicator of a NavigationLink in a list

Tags: list, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am trying to build something like below. The only missing piece is the value at the end, near the disclosure indicator.
Any idea how to add that value using SwiftUI?

I have a list and the list element is a NavigationLink. I am passing a Binding var to the destination where I select from multiple options the value of that var.

I want to show 'None' in case no selection is done at that moment or the selected value when a selection is done in the destination view.

[image]

Comment: Use an `HStack { Text("label") Spacer() Text("secondary") }

Comment: That is an "old" style of a `Picker` the `.pickerStyle(.menu)` gives you a similar look   inside a `List` or a `Form` it just doesn't show in a `NavigationLink` style page anymore. I think this was the standard `menu` 2 OSs ago?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, guys. It really helped. I managed to do it. I will post the final solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to include the content inside a Form or a List.

1. When using a Form with a TextField:

```
Form {
    HStack {
        Text("Label")
        
        TextField("Label", text: $label)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
    }
}
```

2. When using a form with a NavigationLink:

```
Form {
    NavigationLink {
        DestinationView()
    } label: {
        Text("Category")
            .badge("None") // this will show the secondary text near the disclosure indicator
    }
}
```

And then you can play form here and display as badge the content you want (a selection made in the destionation).